# vb.net gridview not filling properly

Tags: sql, vb.net, gridview

So i have this code written...

```
Public Class PrikazUgovora
    Private myConn As SqlConnection
    Private myCmd As SqlCommand
    Private Sub btnPretraziUgo_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPretraziUgo.Click
        Dim tblKorisnik As New DataTable
        myConn = New SqlConnection(Pom.GetConnString())
        myCmd = myConn.CreateCommand

        myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("KliUgoPick", DateTimeUgovora.Value)
        myCmd.CommandText = "select * from klijent"
        Try
            myConn.Open()
            Dim reader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader()

            'test to confirm data received
            Dim dt = New DataTable()
            reader.Read()

            dt.Load(reader)
            DataGridViewUgo.DataSource = dt
            DataGridViewUgo.AutoGenerateColumns = True
            DataGridViewUgo.Refresh()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error")

        Finally
            If myConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                myConn.Close()
            End If
        End Try


    End Sub


End Class
```

And problem Is that i have five records but for some strange reason my gridview is filling only four, leaving first from table not showed the one with ID = 1

same thing happens if I write select * from klijnet where kli_id = 1...

Funny is that in sql this query's works like a charm...

Comment: Have you put a break point after the `dt.Load()` line and using the debugger to see what `dt.Rows.Count` is equal to?

Comment: Why are you using a datareader... I would look up SQL Data Adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely cause is that you are doing a `reader.Read()` which reads the first record. Then you try to fill the datatable.. .the reader has already read the 1st one. I think you may be confusing some of objects here.

Update it to something like this:

```
Public Class PrikazUgovora
    Private myConn As SqlConnection
    Private myCmd As SqlCommand
    Private Sub btnPretraziUgo_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPretraziUgo.Click

        Dim tblKorisnik As New DataTable
        myConn = New SqlConnection(Pom.GetConnString())
        myCmd = myConn.CreateCommand

        myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("KliUgoPick", DateTimeUgovora.Value)
        myCmd.CommandText = "select * from klijent"
        Try
            myConn.Open()
            Dim adapter As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
            adapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(myCmd.CommandText , connection)
            adapter.Fill(tblKorisnik)
            DataGridViewUgo.DataSource = tblKorisnik
            DataGridViewUgo.AutoGenerateColumns = True
            Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error")

        Finally
            If myConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                myConn.Close()
            End If
        End Try


    End Sub


End Class
```

See this information on the SQL data adapter:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Comment: Thank you little diffrent regarding the code but adapter solves it :) cheers mate